# Powershell XML Adding Child Element

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

Wanting to add another child element in system.web element.
So far I have tried a number of ways, however, non have worked.
I have created this code, which I'm not sure is close or not.

Code so far:

```
#setting variables
$path = "H:\PSTesting\Logs\ExerciseXml.xml"
$xml = Get-Content $path

#Creating element
$child = $xml.CreateElement("Test")

#setting attributes
$child.SetAttribute('Testing','hey = "something"')

#adding attributes to the location
$xml.'system.web'.AppendChild($child)

#save file
$xml.Save($path)
```

Below is my XML which needs to be changed.
Current:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<configuration>
    -<system.web>
        <authentication mode="None"/>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="false"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Below is the desired outcome from running the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<configuration>
    -<system.web>
        <authentication mode="None"/>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="false"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
        <Testing Hey = 'something'>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close, just few changes:

```
#setting variables
$path = "H:\PSTesting\Logs\ExerciseXml.xml"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $path

#Creating element
$child = $xml.CreateElement("Testing")

#setting attributes
$child.SetAttribute('hey','something')

#adding attributes to the location
$xml.configuration.'system.web'.AppendChild($child)

#save file
$xml.Save($path)
```

By the way, you might want to remove `-` from your example as they're misleading (`xml` doesn't actually contain them and they're only visible while opening it from programs like IE)

**Edit**: as mentioned by [Rohin Sidharth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081819/9902555), as a best practice would be good to specify the type (although PowerShell will detect it automatically as long as the file format is correct).

**Edit2**: to clarify what was wrong:

```
$child = $xml.CreateElement("Test")
```

This would create element named `Test` while you wanted `Testing` based on your desired output.

```
$child.SetAttribute('Testing','hey = "something"')
```

This would create attribute `Testing` with value `hey = "something"`

```
$xml.'system.web'.AppendChild($child)
```

This won't work as correct path is `$xml.configuration.'system.web'` instead of `$xml.'system.web'`.

Comment: Damn I was so close. Ty for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that Robdy's answer would work because it does not address the real problem which is the `Get-Content` command which reads your xml as a text file. Hence, the xml properties and methods used in the script would not work.

However, the answer is really simple: TypeCasting the `$xml` to `[xml]`

```
#setting variables
$path = "H:\PSTesting\Logs\ExerciseXml.xml"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $path                 #typecasting to xml here

#Creating element
$child = $xml.CreateElement("Test")

#setting attributes
$child.SetAttribute('Testing','hey = "something"')

#adding attributes to the location
$xml.'system.web'.AppendChild($child)

#save file
$xml.Save($path)
```

Like Robdy mentioned, the `-` is misleading. That is not xml format.

Comment: Nice catch - that's a good practice to specify type. However, in this particular example it'll be done automatically by PowerShell (as long as the file format is correct)

Comment: I figured it would but didn't work for me when i tried and i have PS 5.1. Besides typecasting lets me to not depend on the mercy of powershell.

Comment: Apologies for the '-'. This isn't not usually there, its just a collapsed xml. Did it so simplify my data. Ty for the spot.